# FreeRTOS: How to alternate 2 tasks

Tags: esp32, freertos

I want to create 2 tasks on an ESP32, one doing some computing (calculate arrays of x-y coordinates) and one displaying curves on a TFT display.
The first task will fill in the arrays of coordinates, then tell the second task to update the display.
While the display is being updated, then the first task can begin calculating the next array of coordinates.

Each task will be executed on a different core. And I intend to use 2 sets of arrays so there is no problem of memory access.

My question is: what mechanism should I use to be sure that task2 is launched only when task1 is finished, and then task1 is launched just after task2 has begun? Is it a semaphor or direct notification?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a queue: you set up both tasks, and task 1 calculates the coordinates, and when done pushes them onto the queue.

Task 2 listens on the queue, and every time a new set of coordinates comes in, it updates the display and then goes back to checking the queue. You can make it block, ie wait for new data if there is no other work task 2 needs to do.

You don't even have to wait until task 1 is completed -- you can start updating the display while it is still working. If that is a problem, then just don't put the data on the queue until it is all done.

Comment: Thanks Oliver, it makes sense.
I'd need to add some information indicating the beginning and end of each image (made of the curves) so that task2 knows when to erase the display.
Can you provide a link to the API queue?